# Яке походження слова “гіпюр”?

Tags: етимологія, іменники, запозичені-слова

У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghipjur) пише:

> **ГІПЮ́Р**, у, чол. Сорт мережива з опуклим узором. Розчервоніла коло печі Уляна ступав поруч Карпа, в тісній кофті з рожевого гіпюру (Василь Кучер, Трудна любов, 1960, 163).

Однак зацікавилась, яке ж походження цього слова. Звернулась в [ЕСУМ](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page=515), однак такого слова там не знайшла.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%96%D0%BF%D1%8E%D1%80) знаходимо:

> **Гіпю́р** (*фр. guipure, від guiper — «обвивати»*) — сорт мережива з опуклим узором.

Очевидно, ця інформація взята з [Словника іншомовних слів Мельничука](http://slovopedia.org.ua/42/53395/280392.html):

> **гіпю́р** 
>   (*франц. guipure*).

Таку ж інформацію знаходимо у російськомовних джерелах, наприклад, у [Етимологческому онлайн-словаре русского языка Крылова Г.А](https://krylov.lexicography.online/%D0%B3/%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8E%D1%80).

На жаль, більше інформації  про етмологію цього слова не знайшла.